# Running applications indicator in Ubuntu Dock

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, slack

When an application is running, there is a small red dot next to the icon on the GNOME launcher sidebar (Ubuntu Dock). When two instances of the same application are running, there are two small red dots.

When I launch Slack to connect to my employer's workspace, the Slack application launches a Chrome page to authenticate my credentials. When that happens, I see two small red dots against the Slack icon. How do I get it to show me one red dot against Slack and one red dot against Chrome? I know it's possible because this is the behaviour on my other PC, which runs Fedora.

Comment: Comparing with Fedora is a bit tricky here. Ubuntu comes with the GNOME Shell extension Ubuntu Dock by default which turns the GNOME Dash into a fully-fledged dock, whereas Fedora doesn't. Also are you running the same version of GNOME Shell in both Ubuntu and Fedora?

Comment: @pomsky thanks - I didn't know about Ubuntu Dock. Yes, both are running the same version 3.36.x - Ubuntu is on 3.36.3 while Fedora is now running 3.36.4 but was recently also running 3.63.3 with the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it's a chrome instance spawned from Slack and Gnome thinks it's another Slack window.

Does it do the same if Chrome is opened before Slack?

As a workaround, you could open Chrome first and cut/paste the address that Slack launches into the open Chrome window (a bit naff, I'll admit, but it technically solves your problem).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I open Chrome first, then Slack opens the authentication page in a new tab of the existing Chrome window and the red dot remains against Chrome (not Slack). It's only when Chrome is not running at all that I get two red dots against Slack. But on Fedora, using the exact same version of Chrome, I get the intuitive behaviour of having a red dot against Chrome even when it wasn't running before. So it must be some config setting.